# Error #1241 - MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy manipulando una base de datos, y en esta contengo dos tablas(llámense, tabla original, tabla antigua ), con las mismas columnas, excepto la **Primary Key**, la cual es un Auto Incremental. Para hacer el traspaso de datos de la tabla antigua a la original, paso todas sus columnas, excepto la columna "id", la cual es mi PK. Al hacer el traspaso de los datos, me tira un error:

> #### 1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

He googleado bastante, y he visto varias respuestas a estos mismo casos, pero en situaciones distintas a la mía, es por eso que he decidido pedir ayuda, a ver si pueden ver el error presente en mi código.
Además, en el script tengo definido de esta manera la columna **nombre**, y al no tomar en cuenta la PK, espero comparar los datos por el nombre.

> UNIQUE KEY `nombre` (`nombre`)

En este momento lo he probado con dos códigos diferentes, que buscan tener la misma función, adjunto el código de ambas consultas, asumir que **sucursal2** = tabla antigua y **sucursal** = tabla original:

> Consulta 1

```
INSERT INTO sucursal (nombre,direccion,telefono,emails,mesas,descuento_propio,venta_sin_stock,activo,created_at,updated_at,producto_pedido_id,rut,rubro,latitud,longitud)
SELECT (s2.nombre,s2.direccion,s2.telefono,s2.emails,s2.mesas,s2.descuento_propio,s2.venta_sin_stock,s2.activo,s2.created_at,s2.updated_at,s2.producto_pedido_id,s2.rut,s2.rubro,s2.latitud,s2.longitud)
FROM  sucursal2 as s2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sucursal as s1 WHERE s1.nombre = s2.nombre);
```

> Consulta 2

```
INSERT INTO sucursal (nombre,direccion,telefono,emails,mesas,descuento_propio,venta_sin_stock,activo,created_at,updated_at,producto_pedido_id,rut,rubro,latitud,longitud)
SELECT (s2.nombre,s2.direccion,s2.telefono,s2.emails,s2.mesas,s2.descuento_propio,s2.venta_sin_stock,s2.activo,s2.created_at,s2.updated_at,s2.producto_pedido_id,s2.rut,s2.rubro,s2.latitud,s2.longitud)
FROM  sucursal2 as s2
LEFT JOIN sucursal as s1 ON (s2.nombre = s1.nombre)
WHERE s1.nombre IS NOT NULL;
```

Ambas consultas me arrojan el mismo error. Cabe destacar que ambas tablas se han creado con el mismo script, por lo tanto error de definición de las columnas no debería porque haber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Puedes probar de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO sucursal 
    (
        nombre, 
        direccion, 
        telefono, 
        emails, 
        mesas, 
        descuento_propio, 
        venta_sin_stock, 
        activo,
        created_at, 
        updated_at,
        producto_pedido_id,
        rut, 
        rubro, 
        latitud,
        longitud
    ) 
    SELECT 
        s2.nombre, 
        s2.direccion, 
        s2.telefono, 
        s2.emails, 
        s2.mesas, 
        s2.descuento_propio, 
        s2.venta_sin_stock, 
        s2.activo, 
        s2.created_at, 
        s2.updated_at, 
        s2.producto_pedido_id, 
        s2.rut, 
        s2.rubro, 
        s2.latitud, 
        s2.longitud
    FROM  sucursal2 s2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sucursal s1 ON (s2.nombre = s1.nombre)
    WHERE s1.nombre IS NULL;
```

Aquí la subconsulta hace un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` entre las dos tablas, filtrando aquellas filas donde `s1.nombre` sea `NULL`, o sea, donde el valor de `s2.nombre` no existe en `s1`, que serían las filas que habría que insertar.

Prueba y dime cómo te ha ido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la invitación. Y lo he probado y me ha funcionado perfectamente!, muy agradecido!.

Comment: Hola,  @ACedano 
En este momento, necesito pasar los datos de una tabla a otra, pero copiar y pegar, sin condiciones, tengo los mismos campos, con las mismas características, dejé todo tal cual, y me tira este mismo error anterior. Te muestro mi código:

Comment: `INSERT INTO producto_detalle (id,producto_id,precio_compra,precio_venta,iva,ultima_compra,proveedor_id,descuento,stock_ideal,stock_maximo,stock_id,consumo_promedio,multiplo_compra,mercaderia,sucursal_id,activo,created_at,updated_at,stock)
SELECT  (p2.id, p2.producto_id, p2.precio_compra,p2.precio_venta,  p2.iva, p2.ultima_compra,p2.proveedor_id,p2.descuento, p2.stock_ideal,p2.stock_maximo, p2.stock_id, p2.consumo_promedio,p2.multiplo_compra, p2.mercaderia, p2.sucursal_id, p2.activo,p2.created_at, p2.updated_at,p2.stock)
FROM  producto_detalle_antiguo p2;`

Comment: @DiegoI.Herrera no uses paréntesis en el `SELECT`, prueba así: `INSERT INTO producto_detalle ( id, producto_id, precio_compra, precio_venta, iva, ultima_compra, proveedor_id, descuento, stock_ideal, stock_maximo, stock_id, consumo_promedio, multiplo_compra, mercaderia, sucursal_id, activo, created_at, updated_at, stock ) SELECT p2.id, p2.producto_id, p2.precio_compra, ... ` sigue aquí con las columnas y terminas la sentencia con el `;`, o sea, no paréntesis en la parte del `SELECT`. Si aún así no funciona, prueba el `SELECT` sólo y mira a ver si no arroja ningún error.